# Any examples of a 2sxc app with an export option

Tags: .net, excel, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I'm looking for a way to export data to excel from a 2sxc app.
I know it has a built in function to export items to some xml file, but I would like to do this in excel. Perhaps there are some example apps which can do that somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite an answer, but you can open XML files with Excel and save the result as a CSV file.

Comment: Joe is right - the XML is optimized to be editable in Excel.